# How to replace all RGB values in an image if that RGB value belongs to a list

Tags: python, numpy

I need to change all RGB values in an image if that RGB value is on my list without a loop.

I know that in order to change a RGB value I just need to do this:

```
img[np.all(img == (99, 121, 109), axis=-1)] = (255,255,255)
```

But the value `(99, 121, 109)` in my case belongs to a list, for example

```
   rgbL = [[99, 121, 109], 
           [102, 118, 107], 
           [102, 126, 114], 
                   .......,
           [105, 114, 101]]
```

In order to change ALL RGB values in an image that belongs to my `rgbL` list, I need to loop to ALL values of my `rgbL`.  But my list is too long. Is there a way that I can do this without a loop?

Comment: do you mean by doing this? for rgb in rgbL: img[np.all(img == rgb, axis=-1)] = (255,255,255)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no fast way to do this. Whether you use a loop or an optimized numpy solution, under the hood you have to check each pixel against each element of `rgbL`. Given all that, you can use [`isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) combined with a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) [`view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) of the data to perform the correct grouping.

The trick is to make a [custom type](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) that represents pixels. That way, you can compare entire elements rather than color channels, which is what `isin` does by default.

```
pixel = np.dtype([('r', img.dtype), ('g', img.dtype), ('b', img.dtype)])
```

You can not define the pixel datatype as a sub-array type like this `pixel = np.dtype((img.dtype, img.shape[-1]))`. That will cause an error when you try to view the data.

You can now view `img` as a 2D array of `pixel` elements, rather than a 3D array of `uint8` or `float`, as the case may be:

```
data = img.view(pixel).squeeze(axis=-1)
```

You can do the same with your list:

```
rgbA = np.array(rgbL).view(pixel).squeeze(axis=-1)
```

You can also do

```
rgbA = np.array([tuple(p) for p in rgbL], dtype=pixel)
```

You can't use `np.array(rgbL, dtype=pixel)` because the elements will not be initialized correctly in this case.

Now `isin` will give you the mask you want:

```
mask = np.isin(data, rgbA)
```

You can apply the mask directly:

```
data[mask] = 255
```

If you want to set a value that differs between channels, remember to use a tuple to specify pixel entries:

```
>>> data[mask] = (255, 255, 255)  # OK
>>> data[mask] = [255, 255, 255]
ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 1 output values where the mask is true
```

Since `data` is a view into `img`, you are done.

**Note:** This will only work if your image is contiguous in the third dimension. Otherwise, you will not be able to use the same datatype for both arrays. If that is not the case, you will have to copy the image data so that it is contiguous at least in the third dimension. For most sane arrays that aren't weird views across a hyperspectral image or something, you will be OK.

**TL;DR**

```
pixel = np.dtype([('r', img.dtype), ('g', img.dtype), ('b', img.dtype)])

def replace(img, pixels, value):
    data = img.view(pixel).squeeze(-1)
    pixels = np.array(pixels, dtype=img.dtype).view(pixel).squeeze(-1)
    data[isin(data, pixels)] = tuple(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

if this works for a single colour:

```
img[np.all(img == (99, 121, 109), axis=-1)] = (255,255,255)
```

this should work for a list:

```
img[np.all(img in rgbL, axis=-1)] = (255,255,255)
```

Comment: got this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

use a cv2 LUT (look up table) - you can define your own and specify your replacements directly that way.

Comment: I believe a LUT only allows you to map a set of **greyscale** values (i.e. a single channel) to a set of colours, but here the OP wants to map a set of **colours** (i.e. 3 channels) to a new set of colours.