# If count_amount of RGB row (numpy array) is even or not even,how can the condition related exclude or not exclude the final row where the RGB applied?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I continued working on that code (the current version will be posted following the introduction) and set an algorithm that edits the image in accordance with a specific pattern. The code is related to my prior post:

[How can a specific row of (RGB) values in numpy be sought for, in order to replace said row with a different set of (RGB) values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76774224/how-can-a-specific-row-of-rgb-values-in-numpy-be-sought-for-in-order-to-repla)

Said pattern (Can be found in the "if"-section of the code:

- After the RGB (row) value of an array has been counted, and the counted amount equals an even number, then let every row with that value, including the final row with that value, be edited.
- After the RGB (row) value of an array has been counted, and the counted amount equals an not even number, then let every row with that value, excluding the final row with that value, be edited.

The current code does need to be efficient, currently for an 1366 x 768 .PNG image it'd need ~Month< to compute. When the computation is finished, then the resulting image is supposed to be saved.

The "even" number condition does already work I believe, I do not believe the "not even" number condition is already in effect.

How can that pattern be coded effectivly?
How could I code this to be efficient, so if said code is run, it'd complete the computation on the same day?

After this statement the current code will be posted, notes are present in said code,
thanks for every comment and every answer.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
path = "insert_path_here"                           #PATH OF IMAGE THAT IS TO BE EDITED
A = np.array(Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))       #NUMPY ARRAY FROM PATH INTO RGB VALUE

R = 1; G = 1; B = 1
for R in range(1, 254):
    for G in range(1, 254):
        for B in range(1, 254):
            C = (((A == [R, G, B]).all(axis=2)).sum())    #COUNT HOW OFTEN RGB IS PRESENT (IN ROW)
            CE = C[C % 2 == 0];                           #CONDITION "IF COUNT IS EVEN AMOUNT"
            CO = C[C % 2 != 0];                           #CONDITION "IF COUNT IS NOT EVEN AMOUNT"
            #print(C, CE, CO);                            #PRINT COUNT VALUES IF NEEDED
            print(R, G, B)                                #PRINT "CURRENT RGB" VALUES (IN TERMINAL)
            if CE.size != 0:                              #IF ROW NOT EMPTY (!NEEDED TO RUN!)
                #print("EVEN",C-0)                        #PRINT HOW MANY ROWS ARE TO BE PROCESSED (IF EVEN)
                A[(A == [R, G, B]).all(axis=2)] = [1, 1, 1] #HAS TO READ EVERY ROW
                #print(A)
            if CO.size != 0:                              #IF ROW NOT EMPTY (!NEEDED TO RUN!
                #print("ODD",C-1)                         #PRINT HOW MANY ROWS ARE TO BE PROCESSED (IF ODD)
                A[(A == [R, G, B]).all(axis=2)] = [255, 255, 255] #HOW TO EXCLUDE LAST ROW OF SAID VALUE?
                #print(A)
Image.fromarray(A).save('NEWIMG.PNG')
```

The section where `if CO.size != 0:` applies, when `A[(A == [R, G, B]).all(axis=2)]` searches the rows, is the section that is to let the final row of where the RGB value applies, to remain as it was prior. (not change)

Comment: In your code, you only count in the range `[1, 254)`, but this means that, for example, the color `(0, 128, 128)` is not counted and will not be changed. Is this the behavior you expect?

Comment: The intend is to check every RGB value, so including [0,0,0] to [255,255,255]. If the amount of which a value is present is even, then configured should be every row of that value (including the last row where it occurs) and if not even, then every row of that value (except the last row where it occurs) should be configured. I would probably just have to let the range be (0, 256) for that, right? @ken

Comment: From your description, the range `(0, 256)` seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to handle RGB as a set and do not read/write each channel separately.

In such cases, packing RGB into a single value can greatly improve performance and simplify implementation.

For example, you can use the following formula:

```py
packed = r * 1000**2 + g * 1000 + b
```

For instance, `(50, 100, 200)` can be packed as `50100200`.

You could calculate yourself like this, but there is a more efficient way.
By converting the image to RGBA, i.e. 8 bits x 4 channels, and then just treating it as an array of 32-bit integers.

```py
image = Image.open(path)
image = np.array(image.convert("RGBA"), dtype=np.uint8).view(np.uint32)
print(image.shape)  # (768, 1366, 1)
print(image.dtype)  # uint32
print(image[0, 0])  # [4289506476]
```

This is the same as the following calculation (in little-endian environments):

```py
packed = a * 256**3 + b * 256**2 + g * 256 + r
```

Note that I have presented this formula for your knowledge, but you will not do this calculation yourself.
For example, if you want a packed value for a specific color, you can do the following:

```py
r, g, b = (50, 100, 200)
packed = np.array([r, g, b, 255], dtype=np.uint8).view(np.uint32)[0]
print(packed)  # 4291322930
```

Once you have a packed-value image, you no longer need to use fancy methods to handle colors.

- If you want to replace the color: `A[A == color] = new_color`.
- If you want to count the color: `np.count_nonzero(A == color)`.
- If you want to count for all colors: `np.unique(A, return_counts=True)`.

For the exclusion of the last row, `np.unique` has the feature to return the index of the first occurrence of each color. So, by flipping the image upside down, the index of the last occurrence can be retrieved. This allows us to compare only the last row for each color.

Here is the complete code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


def count_colors(image):
    image = np.array(image.convert("RGBA"), dtype=np.uint8).view(np.uint32)

    color_for_even = np.array([1, 1, 1, 255], dtype=np.uint8).view(np.uint32)[0]
    color_for_odd = np.array([255, 255, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8).view(np.uint32)[0]

    # return_index will return the FIRST occurrences of each color.
    # So, if we flip the image, it will return the LAST occurrences.
    colors, indices, counts = np.unique(image[::-1, ::-1], return_index=True, return_counts=True)

    # Count colors.
    even_condition = np.isin(image, colors[(counts % 2) == 0])
    odd_condition = ~even_condition

    # Since the indices are for the flipped image, flip them back to match the original image.
    last_index_of_each_color = image.size - indices - 1
    last_row_of_each_color = last_index_of_each_color // image.shape[1]  # row = index // width

    # We know the last_row_of_each_color, but the color may appear more than once in the last row.
    # So, for each last row, we extend to a boolean map that represents the columns in which the color appears.
    column_mask_for_each_last_row = image[last_row_of_each_color].squeeze() == colors[..., np.newaxis]

    # This is what we want to do, but it does not work in numpy.
    # odd_condition[last_row_of_each_color][column_mask_for_each_last_row] = False

    # Instead, we need to do this. Logically the same.
    color_idx, column_indices_for_each_last_row = np.where(column_mask_for_each_last_row)
    odd_condition[last_row_of_each_color[color_idx], column_indices_for_each_last_row] = False

    # Finally, we can fill colors.
    image[even_condition] = color_for_even
    image[odd_condition] = color_for_odd

    # Don't forget to restore the image to its original dtype.
    image = image.view(np.uint8)

    # Also, don't forget to convert the image to RGB if necessary.
    return Image.fromarray(image).convert("RGB")


input_image = Image.open("./input.png").convert("RGB")
result_image = count_colors(input_image)
result_image.save("./output.png")
```

This function scans a row for each unique color, so the execution speed is highly dependent on the number of colors that appear in the image. For a randomly generated 1366 x 768 image, it took more than 5 seconds, but for an image with fewer colors, such as a photograph, it would be much faster than that.

Comment: Which line in your code is responsible for ensuring that if the count_value of a RGB_value is not even, that "every row except the last row" of said RGB_value should be configured?

The pattern needed is:
If counted_rows(of_RGB_value) = even number,
then edit all even rows of said RGB value (including *its* final row)
If counted_rows(of_RGB_value) =/= even number,
then edit all even rows of said RGB value (excluding *its* final row)

Thanks for taking the time! @ken

Comment: It seems like your code edits all rows that are counted to be even numbered into [1,1,1,255] and all rows counted to be odd numbered into [255,255,255,255], when the latter should edit every odd numbered row into the color, except the final row (one row) of the array of the considered color. There should be one row when working through the odd rows that should not be edited, its color would have to appear in the arrangement of the final image. I am sorry if I am mistaken with this assessment. @ken

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot that I was planning to solve it later. Sorry about that. I have updated my answer, please check again.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, you know what you are doing. =) (Note: Image edited in up to a minute with this code)

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by focusing on the speed requirements. A `for` loop of length 256^3 in pure python is going to be extremely slow. When possible, you should try and use vectorized numpy operations for efficiency.

To begin with, we only need to consider colors that actually are present in the image:

```py
colors, counts = np.unique(A.reshape(-1, A.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

Even with this greatly reduced subset of colors, iterating over them all in pure python remains extremely slow. For even color counts, we can rewrite the code using `np.isin` to eliminate the `for` loop entirely:

```py
# Define custom pixel dtype for faster isin comparison
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878847/13145954 for more info
pixel = np.dtype([("r", np.uint8), ("g", np.uint8), ("b", np.uint8)])

data = A.reshape(-1, A.shape[-1]).view(pixel).squeeze(-1)
even_colors = colors[counts % 2 == 0].view(pixel).squeeze(-1)
# data is a view of A, so modifying data modifies A
data[np.isin(data, even_colors)] = (1, 1, 1)
```

We can then treat the much smaller remaining case where color counts are odd. I did so using a `for` loop as I couldn't figure out a way to vectorize it.
We disregard the case where a color only appears once, as in that case we won't modify the only row where it appears as that row is also the last one

```py
for color in colors[(counts % 2 == 1) & (counts > 1)]:
    # (i,j) coords where color appears
    coords = np.argwhere((A == color).all(axis=2))
    # max row where the color occurs
    max_row_with_color = coords[:, 0].max()
    # (i,j) coords where the color occurs, excluding last row
    filtered_coords = coords[coords[:, 0] != max_row_with_color]

    A[filtered_coords[:, 0], filtered_coords[:, 1]] = [255, 255, 255]
```

Putting it all together:

```py
import numpy as np
import tqdm

# Generate random image, A
A = np.random.randint(0, 256, (1273, 768, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Extract all colors in image to avoid looping over 256^3 colors, most of which will be unused
colors, counts = np.unique(A.reshape(-1, A.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)

## Replace even colors

# Define custom pixel dtype for faster isin comparison
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878847/13145954 for more info
pixel = np.dtype([("r", np.uint8), ("g", np.uint8), ("b", np.uint8)])

data = A.reshape(-1, A.shape[-1]).view(pixel).squeeze(-1)
even_colors = colors[counts % 2 == 0].view(pixel).squeeze(-1)
# data is a view of A, so modifying data modifies A
data[np.isin(data, even_colors)] = (1, 1, 1)

## Replace odd colors

# Manually loop over colors with odd counts
# We can ignore colors that only appear once, as we don't touch the last row
for color in tqdm.tqdm(colors[(counts % 2 == 1) & (counts > 1)]):
    # (i,j) coords where color appears
    coords = np.argwhere((A == color).all(axis=2))
    # max row where the color occurs
    max_row_with_color = coords[:, 0].max()
    # (i,j) coords where the color occurs, excluding last row
    filtered_coords = coords[coords[:, 0] != max_row_with_color]

    A[filtered_coords[:, 0], filtered_coords[:, 1]] = [255, 255, 255]
```

The above code ran in ~2 minutes on a random 1200x600 image found online.

Comment: This works with no issue, in my case with the images on my computer it takes ~30mins to finish the edit. Thanks for taking the time!